# Can't get JQuery to work

Tags: jquery

So i have this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3QuSm/1/ for a dropdown list.

```
    $(".image-box").mouseover(function() {
    $(".expand-box").show();   
}).mouseout(function() {
    $(".expand-box").hide();
});
```

This works just fine, but when i try to integrate it in my application the JQuery doesn't work. I'm kind of new with JQuery and I don't really know where to put it. My code is something like http://pastie.org/8042113. Any help?

Comment: are you sure you did include the jquery file in your html (index) ?

Comment: Wrap your code in `$(document).ready(function(){ /* your code here */ });`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make use of [`$(document).ready()`](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) (or `$(window).load()`).

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    ... /* Your code here */
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3QuSm/5/

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your code in the `ready` or `load` event, so that it runs after the elements in the page has been created:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".image-box").mouseover(function() {
    $(".expand-box").show();
    alert("something");
  }).mouseout(function() {
    $(".expand-box").hide();
    alert("something");
  });

});

</script>
```

When you put the code in jsfiddle, it will by default put it in the `load` event, that's why it works there and not in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait till the DOM is ready for manipulation.
put your code in `document.ready()`

here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3QuSm/8/

Comment: Your fiddle already has the code in the `load` event, so jQuery will not put the code in the `ready` event, it will just call the handler immediately, as the `ready` event has already happened.

Comment: ohk, jsfiddle has already implemented `$(window).load(function()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the JQuery isn't loaded, navigate to that page in your localhost, and see the source code, open the link that points to the JQuery if you can see the code, it is loaded.

Try this to see if the JQuery is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert ("JQuery working!");
});
//-->
</script>
```